# Julia - check elementwise if elements of vector x are in the vector y

Tags: vector, julia, element, broadcasting

I want to check elementwise (or broadcast) if the elements of vector x are in the vector y in Julia like what the function `checkin` does:

```
x = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
y = ["two", "three", "five", "four"]

function checkin(x,y)
    for i = 1:length(y)
        if y[i] ∈ x
            println(true)
        else 
            println(false)
        end
    end
end
checkin(x,y)
```

output:

```
true
true
false
true
```

If I type

```
x .∈ y
```

or

```
x .in y
```

I get an error

As often, I'm sure that there exist a much easier way to do it as writting a 9 line function, but I couldn't find it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
in.(y, Ref(x))
```

You have to wrap `x` in `Ref` or write `(x, )` or `[x]` in order make broadcast always take `x` and not iterate over it.

Note that I have written it so that you check if `y[i]` is in `x` for `i in eachindex(y)` because this was the way your reference implementation was done.

Comment: Many thanks once more @Bogumił Kamiński. Is `Ref` the same as in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/refpointer.jl ?

Comment: Yes, but in this application just think of it as 0-dimensional container holding `x` that has exactly one element. It is better to use `Ref` than e.g. `[x]` because it is immutable and in hot code will not cause Julia to make additional allocations. `(x,)` should be equally fast to `Ref(x)`.